# Updating a bundled resource file

Tags: java, io, java-io

I am doing the following,

```
String str = "this is the new string";
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("path_to_resource");
File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer.write(xml);
writer.close();
```

In the above code I am trying to write to a resource file contained in one of my java packages. After executing the code, my program executes fine but the file just updates the properties file in web-INF and not into the package where it is stored. Can anyone please help me figure how can I achieve that or what am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here, but getClass().getResource(..) will pick up the first matching resource in  your classpath. If that is not what you want, then you might have to look at another way of specifying the wanted file. Also, if the resource is located in a jar, then your construct would fail, since the URL is not accessible as a File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be trying to write to a file stored with your application classes. Depending on the application server, the location you are trying to write to may not be writable or the application may be running from an application archive (a .war file).

You should use an external folder to store configuration and other application data. Typically, you specify this folder via an environment variable or a property specified during deployment.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I had one more question though, what I am trying to achieve by doing this, is modify a properties file to be read by my application at runtime. Can you suggest a proper way to do it?

Comment: You are not being clear. At what point are you trying to modify this file.